# Android + Dolphin + Jetpack - show more comments not working

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web

I'm on Android, and the mobile version's 'show more comments' link on a SO question is not working.

Browser: Dolphin 9.3.1 + Jetpack 2.0

Comment: Works fine on Chrome and Safari on iPhone. Can you try different browsers?

Comment: Not all browsers are supported, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/152859). The site is using JavaScript and each browser has its own implementation of that client side language.

Comment: The cause is the same: unsupported browser. The answer there also applies here.

Comment: No need to shout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that the problem was that the plugin Jetpack 2.0 was somehow preventing the click on the link. The show more comments link worked after I uninstalled the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

We only support the default browsers on mobile devices, and I've failed to reproduce this problem on any of them.

It's not practical for us to support all browser unfortunately, it's just too much effort for too few users.