# Entering a space on mobile site right at the end of the line is not recognised

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

### Background

On mobile precise positioning of the cursor is extremely difficult. When entering a spelling mistake I will usually delete the entire word and retype rather than trying to select the mistake itself. Sometimes deleting an entire sentence and retyping is easier than repositioning the cursor.

### The Bug

When entering a comment on the mobile version of the site if the line is exactly a line long then the space (between words) is not recognised.

For example if I type (as a comment on a question, answer comments are a different length)

> This seems like a good sentence to test the irritating system[SPACE]

Then the space is not recognised (how ever many spaces I add) and so the first word of the next line is run together with the last word of the first line, so

> This seems like a good sentence to test the irritating
> systemwhich

After the word has fallen onto the next line I can go back and reinsert the space as a work around. However; as I say precise positioning on a phone is extremely difficult

Reproducing this bug seems very sensitive to the line being exactly one line long. I had to experiment with long letters (like 'w') and short letters (like 'f') to get it exactly right. My test sentence quoted above is likely to be dependant on my screen size.

Results so far:

**ANDROID**
**Galaxy s3**
Standard Android Browser: exhibits bug  - reported by R Tingle & Rory Alsop
Dolphine browser: exhibits bug
Chrome: no bug

**Galaxy S2**
Standard Android Browser: exhibits bug*

**Galaxy S1**
Standard Android Browser: exhibits bug - reported by yuvi

*In the case of the Galaxy S2 the space appears to "hold", ending up at the end of the line. But on starting the next word the space disappears

**WINDOWS PHONE**
**Lumia 800**
Standard Windows Phone browser: no bug

**APPLE**
**Ipad**
Recent Model: exhibits bug - reported by Rory Alsop

Comment: Looks more like browser issue that fails to wrap words correctly. What browser are you using on your device? Can you try with other browser?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thats possible, however, i tried it with both the standard android browser and the 3rd party dolphine browser. I think I have an old iphone *somewhere* I'll see if I can dig it out

Comment: I'm almost sure you can install and use Chrome on the device. Also, dolphine [isn't supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170283/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Interesting; **Standard android browser**: exhibits bug. **dolphine**; exhibits bug. **Chrome** Does not exhibit bug

Comment: Since the "Standard android browser" is supported this indeed might be a bug, really can't tell - hopefully dev will take a look and be more helpful. :)

Comment: If -1 means "could not reproduce" let me know which platform, i'll add it to my results

Comment: Not my downvote, guess someone thought it's too minor to report.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose. Its been irritating me for weeks though (mostly because going back and entering the space later is really fiddly with the mobile browser)

Comment: The same thing happens to me on android and also occasionally on chrome on win7 and iPad - has been a vague niggle for a few weeks

Comment: @RoryAlsop Interesting, so this isn't only a mobile problem!

Comment: It is only annoying on mobile though, for the reason you gave - selecting the right point to add in your space is difficult.

Comment: @RoryAlsop What android device are you using and which version of the ipad is it

Comment: Galaxy S3. Not sure what version the iPad is. Probably the newest one.

Comment: couldn't reproduce on lumia 800

Comment: I can reproduce this with the standard Android browser (Galaxy S3, 4.3) and on Facebook's mobile site too. Goes away when using FF. I think Shadow Wizard is correct that this is a browser issue regarding text areas.

Comment: Seems like a webkit bug?

Comment: @Sklivvz Intersting, is that the sort of thing that can be worked around from the Stack Exchange side or is it a "It's broken till they fix it" kind of thing