# Does Stack Overflow fix bugs or problems reported on meta?

Tags: support, meta, bug-reports

Today I found two bugs in this site and asked questions about them. My questions were marked as duplicates. That's fine. Is there anyone who views those and fixes bugs in this site?

Comment: The Stack Overflow codebase is self conscious. It tracks and fixes its own bugs.

Comment: There are a lot of things to do, I'm sure that the dev team will get to them when they can (he says still bitterly waiting for a fix to [his own bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187836/entering-a-space-on-mobile-site-right-at-the-end-of-the-line-is-not-recognised))

Comment: No, these bug reports are just there to occupy us.

Comment: @Oded Any record or track or way by which users get to know about self conscious?

Comment: I find it difficult to parse your last comment. I have no idea what it means. Do you understand what the term "self conscious" means?

Comment: Oded is one of the code's keepers. His job is to stroke and feed it

Comment: @Pëkka - and I have the scratches marks to prove it.

Comment: @Oded Pretty sure you just acknowledged that we have sentient bugs. I'm just sayin'

Comment: I think all of ur  terms little difficult for me to understand.. Code keeprs? Codebase? And yes self conscious?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar: I guess your grasp on English is not quite good enough. To spell it out: they are making jokes.

Comment: @TinyTim - was there ever a doubt?

Comment: Jon Skeet presence on SO auto-fix all bugs. (TODO: add in [Jon Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/147423))

Comment: This question must protected or comment would really overflow!

Comment: @Oded I fear the OP here just [missed the joke](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214187/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that was rather obvious from his comments here. This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @Oded of course we can, we just have to teach our lore to newcomers... :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both the developers and the community team regularly patrol *every* meta site in the network, to make sure that all valid [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) reports get attention (among other things). Sometimes, things don't get tagged correctly, but we do often catch those relatively quickly as well.

The order in which bugs are fixed, delayed until another bug is fixed, or put on the back burner for being very low impacting is completely up to the developers - they want to make sure that they're satisfying the broadest group of users possible with their work.

Some bugs are valid, but not very noticeable, and may remain unfixed because it's known that a major change coming up relatively soon is going to make them a bit of a moot point to begin with.

However, we do try to acknowledge each one, and provide feedback on them. If a bug is a duplicate of another, chances are the feedback we've given is on the original - so be sure to check there. If there hasn't been much movement since, you're absolutely free to `@mention` one of us and ask - we're pretty good at responding to that.

There's also a contact link in the footer of every page on every site - if something that seemed minor went major, or you think something just didn't get noticed, you're always free to get in touch with us.

To directly answer: Yes, every (valid) bug report counts.

Comment: I'm sorry, but actually I don't really feel that we get much responses on bug reports.

Comment: @juergend We've been working rather hard lately to change that perception, though that is coming off the heels of a rather large backlog. We have gotten better, and will hopefully continue to do so - is there a particular bug you filed recently that didn't get enough of a response?

Comment: @TinyTim Could you fix [this almost 2-year old UX bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117351/add-show-comments-focuses-text-box-by-default)?

Comment: I wont mark this solution as answer unless u solve all bugs or Jon Skeet Sir show presence on SO... ;-)

Comment: @TinyTim: I just revisited my recent posts and I must admit you really try to reply. I hope people notice the difference.

Comment: @TinyTim Well! If you offer to fix bug just like that, on a silver platter :P! Fixing this would be my xmas gift: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175911/refreshing-the-page-of-a-suggested-edit-audit-kills-the-audit  (Btw you guys have been doing a great job! Keep up with the good work)

Answer (score 8):

There are [4,461 bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+status-completed) which have been marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

There are [10,164 bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), though [403 are not reproducible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+status-norepro) (tagged [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)), [1,416 are by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+status-bydesign) (tagged [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)), and [277 are declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+status-declined) (tagged [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)).

That gives us 4,461 bugs fixed out of 8,068, or a 55.3% clear rate on reported bugs.

So yes, they do get fixed.